# Regex splitting strings on a character, not contained in ()

Tags: regex

I'm trying to split a string on a , where that character is not contained in ().

Example String:

```
`table1`.`lname`,`table1`.`fname`,if(foo is not null,foo,if(bar is not null,bar,table3.baz)),`table3`.`shu`
```

I want to split it into an array looking like

```
(
  0=>`table1`.`lname`
  1=>`table1`.`fname`
  2=>if(foo is not null,foo,if(bar is not null,bar,table3.baz))
  3=>`table3`.`shu`
)
```

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

--
Dave

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can't do it with a regex.  You typically need a recursive descendant parser (or something similar) to match up parentheses which may be nested to arbitrary depth.

I think there have been similar questions here before, but I was having a hard time finding them.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408570/regular-expression-to-parse-an-array-of-json-objects/408641#408641) however should help to explain.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into your favorite language to see if there is a specific module for handling CSV files.  Ruby has CSV (replaced by [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) in recent versions) that would handle your problem just fine.

It is more complicated than a single regex but will get the job done.

Perl has [this Parse::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Parse-CSV-1.00/lib/Parse/CSV.pm) module.

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't very good at this.  Consider the following snippet:

> (a)b(c(d)e)

Where each letter represents a comma (your search target).  Based on your question, you would only want to match comma `b`. The trick is that expressions are generally either greedy or not greedy, with no middle ground.

A greedy expression would see the `(` at the very beginning of the segment and the `)` at the very end and take *everything* inside them, regardless that there are closing parentheses elsewhere. *Nothing* would be matched.

An ungreedy expression would take only the smallest set possible, starting from the beginning.  It would match comma `b`, but also see this segment as one unit: `(c(d)` and then proceed to also match comma `e`.

There are some engines that allow you to count nesting levels, but the expressions are usually ugly and hard to maintain: best to just avoid the feature unless you really understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you are only going to receive **one** pair of parenthesis, then this might work:

```
/(([^,]*\(.*\))|[^,]*)/g
```

Just remember that this will fail if you have a `)` somewhere miscellaneous or if you have more than one set of parenthesis that need to be parsed out.

Comment: The example he uses has two pairs of parenthesis.