# Json alternative for python v2.4

Tags: python, json, compatibility, python-2.4

I want to use json kind of functionality in python 2.4. I know I can use third party module like `simplejson` etc.

But I cannot use a third party module. I have to make use of default python modules only.
I have used json in python v2.6. So is there any alternative for json in v2.4 or can I create such function like `json.load(open(fileName, 'r'))` and `json.dump(self._dict, open(self._fileName, 'w'))`.

I have to use these functions in python 2.4 without any 3rd party module.
or any approach you think?

Comment: Why the aversion to a simple module? That is what the `simplejson` module is **for**. Especially since you are new to Python, I'd not try and recreate a JSON parser at this point.

Comment: thanks... But I don't have to use simplejson(or any 3rd party module).
Reason:- I may have to run my program to some machine where 3rd party module won't be installed

Comment: Then you install the module on the 3rd party machine. Seriously though, if you aren't willing to install the module, then asking how to write your own JSON parser is off-topic for SO as you're very unlikely to get any other answers.

Comment: thanks... Any approach that you think. I don't have to use all the functionality of json, rather only dump() and load() that I have described above.

Comment: Well... you don't need to _install_ a third party module - you just need to _use_ it. If a module doesn't have C-Extensions you can just bundle it with your source and use it directly from there; and if you only need specific functionality you can try to extract the parts of the library you need and make your own module from this. This applies to the built-in libraries as well, you could just copy all functionality you need from the python 2.6 `json` library and backport this to 2.4...

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `str` function to turn a dictionary into a string, which will follow a pattern almost identical to JSON. You can recursively save the properties of the object as a dictionary with the property names as keys for their values. The way to load this object would be slightly more difficult, using regular expressions or something to parse the JSON into key-value pairs. For the issues with that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408570/regular-expression-to-parse-an-array-of-json-objects).