# Efficiently rename/re-map javascript/json object keys within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have some structured JSON data like so. Let's assume this is interchangeable, via [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
[
    {
        "title": "pineapple",
        "uid": "ab982d34c98f"
    },
    {
        "title": "carrots",
        "uid": "6f12e6ba45ec"
    }
]
```

I need it to look like this, remapping `title` to `name`, and `uid` to `id` with the result:

```
[
    {
        "name": "pineapple",
        "id": "ab982d34c98f"
    },
    {
        "name": "carrots",
        "id": "6f12e6ba45ec"
    }
]
```

The most obvious way of doing it is like this:

```
str = '[{"title": "pineapple","uid": "ab982d34c98f"},{"title": "carrots", "uid": "6f12e6ba45ec"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].name = arr[i].title;
    arr[i].id = arr[i].uid;
    delete arr[i].title;
    delete arr[i].uid;
}
```

```js
str = '[{"title": "pineapple","uid": "ab982d34c98f"},{"title": "carrots",      "uid": "6f12e6ba45ec"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(str);
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].name = arr[i].title;
    arr[i].id = arr[i].uid;
    delete arr[i].title;
    delete arr[i].uid;
}

$('body').append("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(arr, undefined, 4)+"</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...or using something more complex (albeit *not* more efficient) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647817/javascript-object-rename-key).

This is all fine and dandy, but what if there were 200,000 objects in the array? This is a lot of processing overhead.

**Is there a more efficient way to remap a key name? Possibly without looping through the entire array of objects? If your method is more efficient, please provide proof/references.**

Comment: Consider creating an array with `{from, to}` pairs, and then using the [`map`](http://www.thatjsdude.com/jsConcepts/concepts/array.html) function to iterate through the `arr`

Comment: FYI, this problem has nothing to do with JSON, unless you want to do string processing to change the keys.

Comment: how do you expect to modify every object in the array without going through the array? that doesn't make sense. Why do you need to remap?

Comment: You *could* compare your way to a regex replace, e.g. `str = str.replace(/"title":/g, '"name":');`. This of course makes certain assumptions on the values the objects can have, but it's easy to do, so why not give that a try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change key name in nested JSON structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518762/change-key-name-in-nested-json-structure)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, if you can make certain assumptions about the values of the objects, you could use a regular expression to replace the keys, for example:

```
str = str.replace(/"title":/g, '"name":');
```

It's not as "clean", but it might get the job done faster.

---

If you have to parse the JSON anyway, a more structured approach would be to [pass a *reviver* function to `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and you might be able to avoid an additional pass over the array. This probably depends on how engine implement `JSON.parse` though (maybe they parse the whole string first and then make a second pass with the reviver function, in which case you wouldn't get any advantage).

```
var arr = JSON.parse(str, function(prop, value) {
   switch(prop) {
     case "title":
        this.name = value;
        return;
     case "uid":
        this.id = value;
        return;
     default:
        return value;
   }
});
```

---

Benchmarks, using the Node.js script below to test 3 times:

```
1389822740739: Beginning regex rename test
1389822740761: Regex rename complete
// 22ms, 22ms, 21ms
1389822740762: Beginning parse and remap in for loop test
1389822740831: For loop remap complete
// 69ms, 68ms, 68ms
1389822740831: Beginning reviver function test
1389822740893: Reviver function complete
// 62ms, 61ms, 60ms
```

It appears as if the regex (in this case) is the most efficient, but [be careful when trying to parse JSON with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408570/regular-expression-to-parse-an-array-of-json-objects).

---

Test script, loading 100,230 lines of the OP's sample JSON:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('test.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": Beginning regex rename test");
    var str = data.replace(/"title":/g, '"name":');
    str = str.replace(/"uid":/g, '"id":');
    JSON.parse(str);
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": Regex rename complete");
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": Beginning parse and remap in for loop test");
    var arr = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].name = arr[i].title;
        arr[i].id = arr[i].uid;
        delete arr[i].title;
        delete arr[i].uid;
    }
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": For loop remap complete");
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": Beginning reviver function test");
    var arr = JSON.parse(data, function (prop, value) {
        switch (prop) {
            case "title":
                this.name = value;
                return;
            case "uid":
                this.id = value;
                return;
            default:
                return value;
        }
    });
    console.log(new Date().getTime() + ": Reviver function complete");
});
```

Comment: Still looks like the regex is the quickest -- I'm only testing this in a simple Node.js instance, I can update your answer with the benchmarks if you like?

Comment: @remus: Yep, that would be cool! Sorry, I don't have the time now to make those tests myself.

Comment: OK, updated. Hope you don't mind I hijacked it like that, but there's a wealth of information there now.

Comment: Awesome! Nice to see that the reviver function is at least a little faster (though not by much). And yeah, you have to be careful with regular expressions and be certain about the input you get.

Comment: Luckily in my case I'm using consistent data with a consistent schema, so it won't be a problem. And also in my case, since I need this to server thousands of requests in Node, I want it to be as efficient as possible. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You could also try to combine both replace options to something like `str.replace(/"(name|uid)":/g, function(match, name) { return keymap[name] || match;})` where `keymap` is something like `{name: '"name":', ....}`. You'd save an additional pass over the string, but at the cost of function calls.

Comment: Yeah, actually I think that's what I will end up doing.

Comment: `var arr = JSON.parse(data, function (prop, value) {
        switch (prop) {
            case "title":
                this.name = value;
                return;
            case "uid":
                this.id = value;
                return;
            default:
                return value;
        }
    });` i am trying to run this code in dev console, but can't. help needed. `data` i am giving as json object
`VM995:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` getting this error

Comment: @Ankuli: seems like you are passing an object to JSON.parse, not a string containing JSON. Don't confuse JavaScript objects with JSON.

Comment: sorry, my mean is javascript object only.
var data = {'title':'testanksuh'};

Comment: @Ankuli: Right. As I said, `JSON.parse` expects to be passed a string, not an object.

Answer (score 17):

Asked this question a long time ago, and since then, I've grown acustomed to using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the job done, more for stability and cleanliness of code than performance. While it's certainly not the most performant, it looks great:

```
var repl = orig.map(function(obj) {
    return {
        name: obj.title,
        id: obj.uid
    }
})
```

If you need a more flexible (and ES6-compatible function), try:

```
let replaceKeyInObjectArray = (a, r) => a.map(o => 
    Object.keys(o).map((key) => ({ [r[key] || key] : o[key] })
).reduce((a, b) => Object.assign({}, a, b)))
```

e.g.

```
const arr = [{ abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50 }, { abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50 }, { abc: 1, def: 40, xyz: 50 }]
const replaceMap = { "abc": "yyj" }

replaceKeyInObjectArray(arr, replaceMap)

/*
[
    {
        "yyj": 1,
        "def": 40,
        "xyz": 50
    },
    {
        "yyj": 1,
        "def": 40,
        "xyz": 50
    },
    {
        "yyj": 1,
        "def": 40,
        "xyz": 50
    }
]
*/
```

Comment: It's very unusual to use map to instigate side effects like that, you should use forEach for that use case. But given map returns a new array you should just do the transform in the callback function and save that array to repl.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another take on the OP's suggestion to use `map()` for clarity (not performance).

```
var newItems = items.map(item => ({
    name: item.title,
    id: item.uid
}));
```

This uses [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the shortcut syntaxes that are possible when there's only one parm passed to the function and only one statement in the body of the function.

Depending on your history with lambda expressions in various languages, this form may or may not resonate with you.

Be careful when returning an object literal in the arrow function shortcut syntax like this.  Don't forget the additional parens around the object literal!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it a little more reusable. Maybe this is a decent approach.

```js
function rekey(arr, lookup) {
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var obj = arr[i];
  for (var fromKey in lookup) {
   var toKey = lookup[fromKey];
   var value = obj[fromKey];
   if (value) {
    obj[toKey] = value;
    delete obj[fromKey];
   }
  }
 }
 return arr;
}

var arr = [{ apple: 'bar' }, { apple: 'foo' }];
var converted = rekey(arr, { apple: 'kung' });
console.log(converted);
```

Comment: your Run code snippet does not work for me. I'm using chrome and mac.

Comment: Are you sure? It's `console.log`, it gets logged in your browser console in the Developer Tools. On my end it seems to work with Chrome on Mac.

Comment: I changed `if (value) {` to `if (typeof value !== "undefined") {` as it was skipping some keys.

Comment: (Sorry for double comments - I hit enter and then was not fast enough on my edit)

I also added an option to Reverse the keys as I needed to take the data back to the original.

    function rekey(arr, lookup, reverse) {
       //Set a default false if  not passed
        if (reverse === undefined) {
            reverse = false;
        }
     for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var obj = arr[i];
      for (var fromKey in lookup) {
       var toKey = lookup[fromKey];
       var value = obj[fromKey];
       if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && !reverse) {...

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6:

```
const renameFieldInArrayOfObjects = (arr, oldField, newField) => {
  return arr.map(s => {
    return Object.keys(s).reduce((prev, next) => {
      if(next === oldField) { 
        prev[newField] = s[next]
      } else { 
        prev[next] = s[next] 
      }
      return prev
    }, {})
  })
}
```

Using ES7:

```
const renameFieldInArrayOfObjects = (arr, oldField, newField) => {
  return arr.map(s => {
    return Object.keys(s).reduce((prev, next) => {
      return next === oldField
        ? {...prev, [newField]: s[next]}
        : {...prev, [next]: s[next]}
    }, {})
  })
}
```

Comment: Like it - I think with ES6 you can reduce it even more too?

Comment: @brandonscript yeah, i don't know how to use a ternary to both set the property and return the object.

Comment: @brandonscript, This actually works, thanks for making me rethink it. Really a lot of ES6 bundled into one example.

Comment: Ah, object support is only available in ES7 (proposed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an npm package named [node-data-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-transform).

Your data :

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 'pineapple',
    uid: 'ab982d34c98f',
  },
  {
    title: 'carrots',
    uid: '6f12e6ba45ec',
  },
];
```

Your mapping :

```
const map = {
  item: {
    name: 'title',
    id: 'uid',
  },
};
```

And use the package :

```
const DataTransform = require("node-json-transform").DataTransform;
const dataTransform = DataTransform(data, map);
const result = dataTransform.transform();
console.log(result);
```

Result :

```
[
  {
    name: 'pineapple',
    id: 'ab982d34c98f'
  },
  {
    name: 'carrots',
    id: '6f12e6ba45ec'
  }
]
```

Maybe it's not the best way for performance, but it's quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonObj = [/*sample array in question*/   ]
```

Based on different benchmarks discussed below, fastest solution is native for:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0, len = jsonObj .length; i < len; i++) {
  arr.push( {"name": jsonObj[i].title, "id" : jsonObj[i].uid});
}
```

I think alternatively without using a frameworks this will be option 2:

```
var arr = []
jsonObj.forEach(function(item) { arr.push({"name": item.title, "id" : item.uid }); });
```

There is always debate between using navite and non-navite functions. If I remember correctly [lodash](http://lodash.com/) argued they were faster than underscore because the use non-native functions for key operations.

However different browsers will produce sometimes very different results. I always looked for the best average.

For benchmarks you can take a look at this:

http://jsperf.com/lo-dash-v1-1-1-vs-underscore-v1-4-4/8

Comment: Why would this be more efficient? Please elaborate.

Comment: According to your benchmark, `Array.map` is actually slower than a `for` loop in both Chrome and Safari. So, that doesn't really help. Moreover, I'm ultimately building this in Node.js, and will be dependent on V8.

Comment: FYI, [here](http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-array-map) is another performance test for this particular problem. I think the result is pretty clear.

Comment: @remus If your problems is associated with NodeJS then this is another story and that is why I mentioned the average across browsers.

Comment: Ouch. The "average across browsers" shows that your solution is slower.

Comment: @still_learning if you have an application that runs in IE7 and Chrome you have to consider both scenarios, correct?

Comment: Well, if IE7 supported `Array.map`, we could start talking about this. Most Chrome builds seem to perform faster with loops as well. But I don't wanna discuss about this, you are right, your solution **could** (theoretically) be faster.

Comment: Thank you all your valuable comments, I updated the answer based on our discussion.

Comment: I think the performance advantage of this solution should not be dicussed in terms of the iteration method (which is trivial to change), but focus on the returning of a new object literal instead of modifying the existing objects.

Comment: @Bergi: So, it's worse because it uses more memory? Or what is your opinion on this?

Comment: @FelixKling: I'd speculate that it's better because [afaik] `delete` is not very optimized in V8, while recurring object literals are. But rather than guessing I'd like someone to do a test on this :-)

Comment: @Bergi: I see. I always forget about the various operations that are optimized (or not). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function replaceElem(value, replace, str) {
            while (str.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                str = str.replace(value, replace);
            }
            return str;
        }
```

call this from main

```
var value = "tittle";
var replace = "name";
replaceElem(value, replace, str);
```