# Best way to rename object properties in ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm still learning js and I need an advice. I get json object from backend, but keys have underscores. What is best practice to rename keys to, for example folder_name to Folder name? The list of properties is known and finished so I can keep new names in constants. At frontend I already use it like this:

```
const showPropertiesList = properties => Object.keys(properties).map(property => (
  <PropertyKey key={property}}>
    `${property}: ${properties[property]}`
  </PropertyKey>
));
```

It's better to use rename function in this map or create separate function before to get all renamed keys with values?

json file:

```
properties {
  folder_name: 'test',
  user_email: 'test@example.com',
  user_agreed: 1,
  site: 'example.com',
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148419/efficiently-rename-re-map-javascript-json-object-keys-within-array-of-objects

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create some kind of a `mapping` object and then use the following combination of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) functions:

```js
const properties = {
  folder_name: "test",
  user_email: "test@example.com",
  user_agreed: 1,
  site: "example.com"
};

const mapping = {
  folder_name: "Folder name",
  user_email: "User email",
  user_agreed: "User agreed",
  site: "Site"
};

const mapped = Object.keys(properties).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc[mapping[key]] = properties[key];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: I think the OP knows how to do that, he/she wants to know the following:  *it's better to use rename function in this map or create separate function before to get all renamed keys with values?*

Comment: @Ele Well, it depends on whether he/she needs this mapped object further or not. If not, it's easier and faster to rename properties inline, as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 7):

try this:

```javascript
const { folder_name: folderName, user_email: email, ...others } = originObject;
const renamedPropsObject = { folderName, email, ...others }
```

Answer (score 1):

Am traveling so I can’t program atm. But I think this will drive you in the correct direction.

```js
    let newArray = array()

    oldArray.forEach(function(value, key) {
        // do stuff here to change the key value
        let newKeyValue = //something 
        newArray[newKeyValue] = value;
    });

    // do stuff with newArray
```

Hope it helps. Not tester it!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping is a good approach, as the previous answer specifies.

In your case you can also do the renaming inline:

```
const showPropertiesList = properties => Object.keys(properties).map(property => (
  <PropertyKey key={property}}>
    `${property.replace('_', ' ')}: ${properties[property]}`
  </PropertyKey>
));
```

Depending on if you want it changed everywhere or just where presented to the user